# Excel - Separating text with numbers, text and brackets into separate cells

Tags: excel, text, split, numbers

This may be a long shot, but is there a way to split the following text into cells:
4 DBL Del (103, 200, 150, 303) to separate cells, first one would be DBL Del (103), second DBL Del (200), third DBL Del (150) and so on?
Numbers can vary, text also, but basically the number indicates how many times text should be repeated and it should get assigned consecutive number from a bracket.
On top of that after a comma, there can be another text eg. 3 TPL Sup (120, 230, 102), 2 SGL St (227, 234).

Comment: Is it possible, Yes.  Vba would be the best approach.

Comment: Agreed, but if Ulka only has experience with formulas, with a bunch of helper columns you can extract word 2 and 3. Next column, extract from the open bracket to the first comma. Next column first comma to second comma. Etc for however many "first numbers" are required. Then "Trim" to erase extraneous spaces, then concatenate back with first helper column. Once that's all working, copy the results and past into a new sheet using paste values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `FILTERXML()`.

```
=TRANSPOSE(LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","</s><s>"),")","")&"</s></t>","//s[1]"),y,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","</s><s>"),")","")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),x&" ("&y&")"))
```

[image]